# How to stop Quartz Scheduler Logging in console

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, log4j2

I have used Quartz Scheduler to schedule a job to execute on the last day of every month. Now for the job Quartz is logging lots of DEBUG information in tomcat console. I have turned off the logging using log4j properties successfully. But now for some reason I have to use log4j2 and now I have to do the same in log4j2.xml file. Can anyone tell me how to set up log4j2 xml configuration to stop quartz scheduler logging?

Thanks,
Surodip

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already checked the log4j2 documentation so you know how to create a basic log4j2.xml file.

I also assume you want to keep some logging but only want to switch off some very verbose logging by `org.quartz.scheduler.*` loggers.

Then, a basic config with quartz loggers switched to ERROR-only could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%p %d %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.quartz.scheduler" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
  </Configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Remko,
Thank you very much for your reply. I have one thing to understand that I have <ROOT level-"DEBUG"> to log some other debug log. So if I go with <ROOT level="DEBUG"> is it going to work?

Comment: Yes that should be fine.

Comment: Yes it worked. Just have to change a little bit. The <logger name="org.quartz" ...>, because all the debug los are coming from classes within org.quartz.* packages. Thanks you very much Remko.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%p %d %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.quartz" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
  </Configuration>
```